# Assigning a value for each dataset and plot it with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply, assign, seq

It can be complicated problem but I will try to explain it as much as I could.

I have a sequenced dataset containing number of observations which should be processed before plotting.

I want do it with a function. because I have another datasets in the directory (around 20)

```
#reproducible dataset
numbers<-c(seq(1,-1,length.out = 601),seq(1,0.98,length.out = 601))
time <- c(rep(seq(90,54144,length.out = 601),times=1),rep(seq(90,49850,length.out = 601),times=1))
data = data.frame(time=rep(time,times=10), mag=rep(numbers, times=10))

myfun <- function(data){
library(dplyr)
data$lag <- data$time - lag(data$time)<0
data$lag[is.na(data$lag)] <- 1
data$set <- cumsum(data$lag)

dfchunk<- split(data, factor((rank(data$set))),drop=TRUE)   #split data

sw_t<-lapply(dfchunk,function(x)x[which(x$mag<0)[1],])
result <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(sw_t),nrow=max(data$set), byrow=TRUE))

all_states <- result[complete.cases(result),]
x_val <- c(rep(seq(3.2,8,0.2),each=max(data$set)))  # ????

final <- data.frame(all_states[1],x_val)         #????
}

data.list <- mixedsort(dir(pattern = "*.txt",full.names = FALSE)) # 

res<-lapply(data.list, myfun)

qplot(x_val, X1, data = data, colour = I("red"))
```

What I do in myfun is;

1. Reshaping the data
2. Split it with a factor
3. apply a function to get first negative value observation
4. getting only the complete.cases (na.omit)

My goals

- I want to assign all X1 column values to one x_val value
- this each x_val repeat numbers should be decided by `nrow=max(data$set)`   (each x_val value 3.2,3.4...8 corresponds to one dataset but each dataset contain different number of observations so this part is complicated!)
- For each dataset use this function and plot it in scatter plot time~x_val using ggplot scatter plot.

So far my function is uncomplete any guidance appriciated.

To *process* **real** data I use following code

```
library(gtools)
data.list <- mixedsort(dir(pattern = "*.txt",full.names = FALSE)) # creates the list of all the csv files in the directory
data  <-  lapply(data.list,function(x){
             tmp <- read.table(file = x, header = T)
             new.df <- select(tmp, V1,V10)
             return(new.df)
             })
swt <- function(data){
library(dplyr)
names(data) <-c("time","Mag")

data$lag <- data$time - lag(data$time) <0
data$lag[is.na(data$lag)] <- 1
data$set <- cumsum(data$lag)
set_nbr <- seq(3.2,8,0.2)
data$curr <- lapply(seq_along(set_nbr),data)
dfchunk<- split(data, factor((rank(data$set))),drop=TRUE)   #split data
sw_t<-lapply(dfchunk,function(x)x[which(x$Mag<0)[1],])
result <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(sw_t),nrow=max(data$set), byrow=TRUE))
#x_val <- rep(data$curr[1], each=nrow(all_states))

 resultt <- rename(result, c  ("X1"="time", "X2"="Mag","X3"="lag","X4"="set","X5"="curr"))

}

 res<-do.call(rbind, lapply(data.list, myfun))
```

so far I am getting error when I assign curr values to the data. @while answer works nice because the set_nbr can be added during the creation of the data. but in the case of real data process I cannot assign it.

Comment: what is the `numbers`variable you refer to when you create `data`? Should it be `mag`?

Comment: @while yes I have edited my question sorry!

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to do. Or maybe your example data is a bit strange. The set is `0` for all rows in this example. `dfchunk` will then only get one list element and the you filter out. Also the sw_t thing is always going to get one row inside one list element. And as set is always 0 the result row fails as you cannot construct a matrix with `nrow=0`.

Comment: @while sorry forgot to add `library(dplyr)` package.

Comment: Ok, that made more sense. I', still not sure I get your end goal here. Could you explain what you want to get as a result for x_val? I don't think I understand points you want to add to your function. Do you want to repeat values based on the number of cases in `data`?

Comment: @while my final goal is: I want to repeat values on the number of cases in `data`. For example, for data1 lets say there are 15 `all_states` so
that means assigned `x_val` value should be repeated 15 times. Finally I want to plot in scatterplot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78904/discussion-between-while-and-thabescity).

Comment: You need to add the set_nbr when you read the data to begin with. The problem with adding that info inside the `swt` function is that you only want one of the values corresponding to each specific dataset and not a whole vector as you don't know which dataset you are processing in there.

Comment: yes that is the point how to add? in reproducible example is ok. But when reading real data I couldn`t made it.

Comment: I added an edit to my answer that adds the sequence as rownames to the dataset list. It should transfer well to your actual dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure I completely get the problem. Really sorry if I missed some point.

I added the set number for x_val in the data.frame's called `set_nbr`.

I modified the test data creation to get a full list like this:

```
data.list <- lapply(seq(3.2,8,0.2), function(x) {
  nrep <- sample(10:20, 1)

  numbers<-c(seq(1,-1,length.out = 601),seq(1,0.98,length.out = 601))
  time <- c(rep(seq(90,54144 + nrep,length.out = 601),times=1),rep(seq(90,49850 + nrep,length.out = 601),times=1))

  data.frame(time=rep(time,times=nrep), mag=rep(numbers, times=nrep), set_nbr=x)
})
```

And then I modified your code to the following:

```
myfun <- function(data){
  require(dplyr)

  data$lag <- data$time - lag(data$time)<0
  data$lag[is.na(data$lag)] <- 1
  data$set <- cumsum(data$lag)

  dfchunk<- split(data, factor((rank(data$set))),drop=TRUE)   #split data

  sw_t<-lapply(dfchunk,function(x)x[which(x$mag<0)[1],])
  result <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(sw_t),nrow=max(data$set), byrow=TRUE))

  all_states <- result[complete.cases(result),]
  
  # repeat the set_nbr the same number of times as there are rows in all_states
  x_val <- rep(data$set_nbr[1], each=nrow(all_states))

  final <- data.frame(all_states[1],x_val) # Your example is fine here
}

# do.call rbind to combine the result to one data.frame
res<-do.call(rbind, lapply(data.list, myfun)) 

qplot(x_val, X1, data = res, colour = I("red"))
```

I hope this answers your question or at least gives you enough pointers for you to solve your problem.

### Edit

You could lapply over the rownames of the data.list instead. This way is would be easy to add a set name to each dataset and use that in your plot.

```
# Create data set example
data.list <- lapply(1:25, function(x) {
  nrep <- sample(10:20, 1)

  numbers<-c(seq(1,-1,length.out = 601),seq(1,0.98,length.out = 601))
  time <- c(rep(seq(90,54144 + nrep,length.out = 601),times=1),rep(seq(90,49850 + nrep,length.out = 601),times=1))

  data.frame(time=rep(time,times=nrep), mag=rep(numbers, times=nrep))
})

# Name each row in the data.list according to the specified sequence
names(data.list) <- seq(3.2,8,0.2)

# Define function to transform the sets based on the list entry name
myfun <- function(data_name){
  require(dplyr)

  # Extract the dataset of interest from the data.list
  data <- data.list[[data_name]]

  data$lag <- data$time - lag(data$time)<0
  data$lag[is.na(data$lag)] <- 1
  data$set <- cumsum(data$lag)

  dfchunk <- split(data, factor((rank(data$set))),drop=TRUE)   #split data

  sw_t <-lapply(dfchunk,function(x)x[which(x$mag<0)[1],])
  result <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(sw_t),nrow=max(data$set), byrow=TRUE))

  all_states <- result[complete.cases(result),]
  x_val <- rep(data_name, each=nrow(all_states))

  final <- data.frame(all_states[1],x_val) 
}

# lapply over the list names instead of the list elements 
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(names(data.list), myfun))

# plot result
qplot(x_val, X1, data = res, colour = I("red"))
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. It works perfectly. It does what I want in the case of reproducible dataset creation. But on the other hand, when I read data and try to add `seq(3.2,8,0.2)` I couldn`t find which part in the `function` I should add this column. Please see my question I modified the last part.